# If there exists a $B$ such that $\lvert f(x)\lvert \le B$ for every $x$, then $g(x) = xf(x)$ is differentiable at $0$.

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

I tried proving the contrapositive, that if $g(x)$ is not differentiable at zero, that $f(x)$ is unbounded. I figured since $x$ is differentiable at $0$, $f(x)$ must not be. So I reasoned that for $f(x)$ to not be differentiable at $0$, there must be a discontinuity at $x = 0$. And then I just horribly confuse myself for hours.

What about for $g(X) = x^2f(x)$?

Answer (score 2):

It's false. Consider $f(x)=\begin{cases}1&\text{if }x\ge0\\ -1&\text{if }x<0\end{cases}$.

Answer (score 0):

Try $$f(x) = \cases{1 & if $x \ge 0$\cr 0 & otherwise}$$